# How to create a trail of circles that follows the mouse?

Tags: javascript, canvas, paperjs

I am attempting to build [something like this](http://paperjs.org/examples/chain/) but instead of it being a line, I want it to be circles. That way I can add a different fill. So far, I am able to have it move on mouse over with this code but only for the first circle. How can I get them to follow in a line?

```
// The amount of points in the path:
var points = 30;

// The distance between the points:
var length = 10;

var path = new paper.Path({
  strokeColor: "white",
  strokeWidth: 50,
  strokeCap: "round"
});

var start = view.center / [10, 1];

// Circle
var circlePath = new Path.Circle({
  center: [80, 50],
  fillColor: "transparent",
  radius: 50
});

var thirdLayer = new Group();

for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));

console.log(path);
// // for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) path.add(end + new Point(i * length, 0));

// // path.addSegments([[657.55, 455], [657.55, 500.5]]);

// path.closed = true;

function onMouseMove(event) {
  path.firstSegment.point = event.point;

  for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
    var segment = path.segments[i];
    var nextSegment = segment.next;
    var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
    vector.length = length;
    nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
  }
  // rect.subtract(nextSegment.point);
  path.smooth({ type: "continuous" });
  var rect = new paper.Path.Rectangle({
    point: [0, 0],
    size: [view.size.width],
    fillColor: "#E50069",
    strokeWidth: 1
  });
  // path.offset(10);
  var drilled = rect.subtract(path);
  secondLayer.removeChildren();
  secondLayer.addChild(drilled);
  rect.remove();

  secondLayer.addChild();
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
  console.log(event);
  path.fullySelected = true;
  path.strokeColor = "#e08285";
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
  path.fullySelected = false;
  path.strokeColor = "#fff";
  path.opacity = 1;
}

// function onFrame(event) {
//   rect.unite(path);
// }
```

Any insight on what way to move forward would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your reference, here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating a possible solution.

```
var points = 25;
var length = 35;
var path = new Path();

var start = view.center / [10, 1];
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));
}

// Create a circle for each segment of the path.
var circles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++) {
    var circle = new Path.Circle({
        center: path.segments[i].point,
        radius: 10,
        strokeColor: 'red'
    });
    circles.push(circle);
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
    for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
        var segment = path.segments[i];
        var nextSegment = segment.next;
        var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
        vector.length = length;
        nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
    }
    // Each time the path is updated, update circles position.
    updateCirclesPosition();
}

function updateCirclesPosition() {
    for (var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++) {
        circles[i].position = path.segments[i].point;
    }
}
```

### Edit

Based on your comment below, here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating how to use the same logic to produce a "reveal image" effect.
The tricks relies on using blend mode to compose layers rather than having to use boolean operations (I originally posted it [here](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/1624#issuecomment-444143848)).

```
// First draw an image as background.
var background = new Raster({
    source: 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg',
    onLoad: function() {
        // Make it fill all the screen.
        this.fitBounds(view.bounds, true);
    }
});

// Draw a rectangle to hide the background.
var maskBase = new Path.Rectangle({
    rectangle: view.bounds,
    fillColor: 'white'
});

// Prepare a group to store the circles that will make the background appear.
var circles = new Group({
    blendMode: 'destination-out'
});

// Assemble both previous element in a group in order to make it display as we
// need.
var mask = new Group({
    children: [maskBase, circles],
    blendMode: 'source-over'
});

// Then prepare the path.
var points = 25;
var length = 35;
var path = new Path();
var start = view.center / [10, 1];
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    path.add(start + new Point(i * length, 0));
}

// Create a circle for each segment of the path.
for (var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++) {
    var circle = new Path.Circle({
        center: path.segments[i].point,
        radius: 10,
        fillColor: 'red'
    });
    circles.addChild(circle);
}

// Update the path when the mouse moves.
function onMouseMove(event) {
    path.firstSegment.point = event.point;
    for (var i = 0; i < points - 1; i++) {
        var segment = path.segments[i];
        var nextSegment = segment.next;
        var vector = segment.point - nextSegment.point;
        vector.length = length;
        nextSegment.point = segment.point - vector;
    }
    // Each time the path is updated, update circles position.
    updateCirclesPosition();
}

function updateCirclesPosition() {
    for (var i = 0; i < path.segments.length; i++) {
        circles.children[i].position = path.segments[i].point;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the great answer. Is there a way I can unite them all using the boolean operation?

Comment: Yes, I think that you could but why would you want to do that ? what effect are you trying to produce (maybe there is a better way) ?

Comment: I am trying to create an effect where a snake trails (like what you have) and have it so you can see an image underneath. Kind of like the snake is cutting through a layer and seeing what's behind it.